# Can we use "nice to meet you" on the phone?

Tags: expressions

I just heard a friend of mine talking on the phone and she was like "nice to meet you". Is this commonly used through the phone?

Comment: I would rather say "Thank you for calling" or "Nice to hear your voice" depending on the purpose of the call. Was it a video call?

Comment: "Nice talking to you" would be more appropriate.  But there's nothing terribly wrong with "nice to meet you".

Comment: Nice to meet you online.

Comment: @Rathony no actually that wasn't a video call! that's why I wan kinda surprised when I heard it!

Comment: @HotLicks thx dear

Comment: @Mysti thx dear

Answer (score 3):

It's not common practice to say "nice to meet you" on the telephone but, if an introduction was made on the call, then I suppose it fits.

> Dave: Sue, have you met Paul?
>   Sue: No. Nice to meet you, Paul.

If it was at the end of the call, a more likely thing to say would be "nice talking to you".

> And that concludes the teleconference; nice talking to you, Paul.